# Small solutions to modular hyperbola

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Fix $\ell\in\Bbb N_{>1}$ and small $0<\epsilon\ll1$.

> Given $r_1,\dots,r_\ell\in(0,1)$ with $\sum_{i=1}^\ell r_i=1$, is it possible to always find $\Omega(p^{\ell\epsilon'})$ solutions $x_i\in\Bbb Z$ to $$\prod_{i=1}^\ell x_i=1\bmod p$$ such that $$0<x_i<p^{r_i+\epsilon}$$
>   holds as $p\rightarrow\infty$ at least for the case $p$ is prime for some $0<\epsilon'<\epsilon$?

At $\ell=1$ we have $x_1x_2\equiv1\bmod p$ is equation of hyperbola.

> How about instead of $$0<x_i<p^{r_i+\epsilon}$$ we seek only $$0<|x_i|<p^{r_i+\epsilon}$$ where $x_i\bmod p$ is in $(-p/2,p/2)$.